# Probability sequence

Tags: probability

Fifty marbles numbered 1 to 50 are placed in a barrel and twenty drawn one at a time without replacement. What is the probability that at least one will be drawn in sequence? i.e. 1 is drawn first, two is drawn second etc.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: There are $50!$ equally likely permutations. We find the probability none is in its proper position. A permutation in which nothing is in its proper place is called a *derangement*. Please see Wikipedia for a count of the derangements. It will turn out that the probability no item is in its proper place is $\frac{1}{e}$ for all practical purposes.

Comment: Only twenty numbers are drawn. I can see the 1/e result as correct if all 50 are drawn but cannot see a method for 20.